grep or sed to delete 1 line after a match (but not the match)?
I'm trying to write a command to amend an xml file to remove the first of each pair of lines with a <display-name> occurrence.
In other words, my file looks like...
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tv guide2go="guide2go" source-info-name="Schedules Direct" source-info-url="http://schedulesdirect.org">
  <channel id="guide2go.68589.schedulesdirect.org">
    <display-name>COMCUKH</display-name>
    <display-name>Comedy Central UK HD</display-name>
    <icon src="https://schedulesdirect-api20141201-logos.s3.dualstack.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/stationLogos/s68589_dark_360w_270h.png" height="270" width="360"></icon>
  </channel>
  <channel id="guide2go.79036.schedulesdirect.org">
    <display-name>INVDIP1</display-name>
    <display-name>ID +1</display-name>
    <icon src="https://schedulesdirect-api20141201-logos.s3.dualstack.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/stationLogos/s79036_dark_360w_270h.png" height="270" width="360"></icon>
  </channel>

and I want it to look like...
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tv guide2go="guide2go" source-info-name="Schedules Direct" source-info-url="http://schedulesdirect.org">
  <channel id="guide2go.68589.schedulesdirect.org">
    <display-name>Comedy Central UK HD</display-name>
    <icon src="https://schedulesdirect-api20141201-logos.s3.dualstack.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/stationLogos/s68589_dark_360w_270h.png" height="270" width="360"></icon>
  </channel>
  <channel id="guide2go.79036.schedulesdirect.org">
    <display-name>ID +1</display-name>
    <icon src="https://schedulesdirect-api20141201-logos.s3.dualstack.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/stationLogos/s79036_dark_360w_270h.png" height="270" width="360"></icon>
  </channel>

I don't mind if it's the same file, or a new file, I just want it with only the second occurrences of <display-name> from each pair.  TIA.
I've tried a few GREP and SED commands (and a lot of Google searching for anything similar), as I know how to use -v to remove all occurrences of a match, but no joy working between lines at all.

The only difference between the extracts from the two files is COMCUKH and INVDIP1.

Probably don't use regex unless you have full control over the XML. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231382/what-can-i-do-when-a-regular-expression-pattern-doesnt-match-anywhere-in-a-stri

Why don't you learn to work with xmllint for working on XML strings?

Tested with both GNU and BSD (e.g. macOS) tools
sed '/display-name/{N;s/.*\n//;}' file

Basically, when seeing "display-name", read the next line and delete the current one. You can make the pattern more specific if this hits false-positives.
Note that this doesn't check that the next line also matches, so if there is only one it will be deleted. If there are more than two in a row, all even lines will be printed (second, fourth, etc.)

This might work for you (GNU sed):
sed '/<channel id=/{n;d}' file

Find a line containing <channel id=.
Print it and read in the next line.
Delete the line.
Alternative:
sed 'N;/\(display-name\).*\n.*\1/!P;D' file

Append the following line.
If that line contains also contains display-name, do not print the first line.
Otherwise, print the first line and then delete it.
N.B. The D command prints upto and including the first newline, the sed cycle will only read in the following line if the pattern space is empty.

If you have sed then you also have awk. Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:
$ awk '!(/<display-name>/ && (f=!f))' file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tv guide2go="guide2go" source-info-name="Schedules Direct" source-info-url="http://schedulesdirect.org">
  <channel id="guide2go.68589.schedulesdirect.org">
    <display-name>Comedy Central UK HD</display-name>
    <icon src="https://schedulesdirect-api20141201-logos.s3.dualstack.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/stationLogos/s68589_dark_360w_270h.png" height="270" width="360"></icon>
  </channel>
  <channel id="guide2go.79036.schedulesdirect.org">
    <display-name>ID +1</display-name>
    <icon src="https://schedulesdirect-api20141201-logos.s3.dualstack.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/stationLogos/s79036_dark_360w_270h.png" height="270" width="360"></icon>
  </channel>

